# save to offline without creating player object using shaka player

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, shaka

```
Class: shaka.offline.Storage
```

have a constructor

```
new Storage(player)

Class: shaka.Player
```

have a constructor

```
new Player(video(non-null), opt_dependencyInjector(opt))
```

but what i trying to do is saving a video url without having a video element in page. Is it possible to do.

It would be nice if i could do this in a background on the main process of electron application.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a video element using JavaScript.  It won't appear on the page.

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
var player = new shaka.Player(video);
var storage = new shaka.offline.Storage(player);
```

Currently, the player require being run inside a page.  This means you can't load Shaka Player in a service worker.  I'm not sure how electron will handle a background process, but it will likely not work because the player requires certain APIs to be available that are not available in service workers.

We (the Shaka team) are also currently working on changing the APIs so that: (1) you can initialize a Player instance initially without a video element, and (2) you can create a Storage instance without a Player instance.  These are requirements to be able to use the player in a service worker.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Another quick question is it possible to choose local file storage as offline storage area ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'local file storage'?  Shaka player uses [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) to store data, which is stored in local files by the browser.

Comment: I mean not using indexedDB may be mongoDB, mysqlDB or any other DB.

Comment: No, there is no way.  Shaka Player only supports IndexedDB.  You could look into [issue #1005](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/1005) for info on how to modify the player to do it.